# Would "adventure" be categorized under "action"?

Tags: php, categories

I was wondering if "adventure" and "action" are in the same category.

Comment: Did this place become libraryoverflow or movieoverflow while I was having dinner? Off topic...

Comment: Thats an EXCELLENT PHP question, it is equivalent to the meaning of life!

Answer (score 2):

Action is where the main character fights off bad guys for the girl.  Adventure is where the main character partakes in a quest to FIND the girl.